# Prism: IEventAggregator in constructor, needed arguments

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to learn `IEventAggregator` and you need to set an `IEventAggregator` in your constructor. But if I want to set the DataContext, I have to pass arguments? I know what is a constructor, but what arguments am I supposed to pass or do I have to set the ViewModel in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this through using store and overriding `OnStartup` in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
public class VehicleStore
{
    public event Action<Vehicle> VehicleCreated;

    public void CreateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        VehicleCreated?.Invoke(vehicle);
    }
}
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        VehicleStore vehicleStore = new VehicleStore();

        CarListViewModel carListViewModel = new CarListViewModel(vehicleStore);
        CreateNewCarViewModel createNewCarViewModel = new CreateNewCarViewModel(vehicleStore);

        CreateNewCarView createNewCarView = new CreateNewCarView()
        {
            DataContext = createNewCarViewModel
        };

        carListViewModel.CreateNewCarView = createNewCarView;

        CarListView carListView = new CarListView()
        {
            DataContext = carListViewModel
        };
        carListView.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```